# Display just the number of comments

Tags: javascript, html, disqus

I'm currently setting up DISQUS and would like to display the number of comments for a specific post.

DISQUS provide a piece of code(http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/) to do this but it outputs in the format "`2 comments`"

Does anyone know if it is possible to display just the number? ie. without the word "Comments"

The documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the text that is rendered by changing the settings of your website on the Disqus admin (see http://disqus.com/admin/settings/appearance/).

By putting the word "comments" inside a css class, you can then selectively render it where you want it to be visible, or set its style to {display: none} where  you only want the number. This is now described in detail in the recent disqus documentation (http://docs.disqus.com/help/3/).